# Cron to trigger a Rails Rake in DigitalOcean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, cron, digital-ocean

I have a rake task that I'd like to schedule a cron to run. My Rails 4 project is hosted on a DigitalOcean droplet is running Ubuntu 12.10 (Nginx + Unicorn).

Here's what I have in crontab:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin/usr/bin
HOME=/
MAILTO="xxx@gmail.com"

* * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'source ~/.bash_profile && cd /home/rails && RAILS_ENV=production bin/rake populate:fetch_nr_songs'
```

However I get this error:

```
/etc/profile.d/rvm.sh: line 9: ps: command not found
/etc/profile.d/rvm.sh: line 10: ps: command not found
/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm: line 96: dirname: command not found
ERROR: Missing proper 'which' command. Make sure it is installed before using RVM!
```

Any fix would be much appreciated thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seems like somethings wrong with RVM installation. Try re-installing it https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin-with-rvm

Note: you can effortlessly manage `crontab` using [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever)